# R function to search and count multiple conditions in same column?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, pipe, multiple-conditions

Is there a way to search for multiple conditions in the same column and then count the number of occurrences?

For example, I want to figure out how many times a specific combination of values (x and then y, x then w, x then z) occur after one another for each respective person.

I tried writing an IF statement but was told that dplyr would be a better route.

```
Dataframe: 
c1      c2
person1  x
person1  y
person1  a
person1  a
person2  x
person2  w
person1  x
person1  z

df %>% select(c1, c2) 
   %>% tally(filter(c2 == "x")
     %>% lead(filter(c2=="y")))
```

Expected results: a subset that displays the total number of times x then y, x then w, x then z, appear for each person.

```
c1                 xy            xw          xz
Person 1           1             0           1         
Person 2           0             1           0
```

## R gives me the following error:

```
  Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
    no applicable methord for 'filter_' applied to an object of class 
"logical"
```

Comment: What was your if statement? I'm interested in what you tried that didn't work. `filter` takes a data frame as its first argument (see the error you got), so you've got your `filter` and `tally` calls inside out. Also is it a given that your data will be in alphabetical order i.e. `lag` would be safe to use?

Comment: I scrapped my work after the solution below got me my desired outcome. I used a traditional if statement with base R on my first attempt and then tried again with dplyr. My data are not in alphabetical order. Lead is what I need because the data are based on dependent sequnce of events. see below..
     df %>% group_by(c1) %>% filter(tally(if(c2=="x" & lead(c2=="y",1) %>% ifelse(tally(c2=="x" & lead(c2=="w",1)))

Comment: It's much easier to read & follow your code if you [edit] it into the question

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)

c1 = c("person1",
       "person1",
       "person1",
       "person1",       
       "person2",
       "person2",
       "person1", 
       "person1") 

c2 =  c("x","y","a","a","x","w","x","z")

df = as_tibble(cbind(c1,c2))
df %>% 
  group_by(c1)  %>% 
  summarise(xy = sum(c2 == "x" & lead(c2, 1) == "y" ),
            xw = sum(c2 == "x" & lead(c2, 1) == "w"),
            xz = sum(c2 == "x" & lead(c2, 1) == "z"))
```

Gives you

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  c1         xy    xw    xz
  <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 person1     1     0     1
2 person2     0     1     0
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply. Your solution worked, however, is there a more efficient way to convert my actual data into vectors? My actual data has hundreds of rows

Answer (score 1):

An option using `spread`.  Create a column by `paste`ing the 'c2' with the `lead` values of 'c2', `filter` only the selected elementss in 'newcol' using `%in%` and `spread` from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   mutate(newcol = str_c(c2, lead(c2)), ind = 1) %>% 
   select(-c2) %>%
   filter(newcol %in% c('xy', 'xw', 'xz')) %>% 
   spread(newcol, ind, fill = 0)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(c1 = c("person1", "person1", "person1", "person1", 
"person2", "person2", "person1", "person1"), c2 = c("x", "y", 
"a", "a", "x", "w", "x", "z")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Going to give this a shot, too. Thank you for the suggestion